# for loop - to iterate or not to iterate?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, printf, line

I'm writing a hangman game using Python, based on a specific set of instructions. I specifically need to use a `for` loop in order to replace all the letters in a word with underscores and in fact I am succeeding in doing so. However I have one slight issue, I'm getting a new line of underscores printed for every letter in my word. Is there a way to get rid of this? Can someone guide me on what is wrong with my logic?

```
word = "test"

def createBlank(word):
    for letter in word:
        blanks = '_' * len(word)
        print(blanks)
```

My result is as you would assume:

```
>>> word
'test'
>>> createBlank(word)
____ #<- only need this line to be printed.. is it even possible using a for?
____
____
____
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeating printing `blanks` for the number of chars in `word`. Just move `print(blanks)` outside `for` loop:

```
word = "test"

def createBlank(word):
    for letter in word:
            blanks = '_' * len(word)
    print(blanks)
```

**DEMO:**

```
>>> createBlank(word)
____
```

But why the need for a `for` loop to print underscore times the `len` of `word`, where you can simply do it this way:

```
word = "test"

def createBlank(word):
    blanks = '_' * len(word)
    print(blanks)
```

Comment: Is that `for` loop needed? Define the `blanks` variable 4 times?

Comment: No, its not. OP is assinging `blank` the same value each iteration.

Comment: @KevinGuan...Nope it's not...I just update my answer

Comment: At this point, `blanks` isn't even needed and he can just let the equation evaluate into `print` like `print('_' * len(word));`

Comment: @AustinWBryan...I don't prefer that approach, as I favorite readability over code squeezing

Comment: goshh, silly me. thanks @IronFist. I don't really know why it is need. To be honest I haven't coded in ages, I'm just playing around with some of my younger brother's papers.. trying to learn something new over the holidays.

Quote:
a. Use a for-loop to replace every letter in the word by ( _ )
b. Every time the user enters a letter to guess, this is passed to this function and:
 if the letter is valid – the letter will replace the underscore in its correct position
 If invalid – one life is decreased and underscore remains

Answer (score 0):

actually You were using this " * len(word) " the wrong because it was running in a loop so it will print it mulitple times

Try this

```
word = "test"

def createBlank(word):
    for letter in word:
        blanks = '_'
        print blanks,
```

an this it runs better

```
from __future__ import print_function # needs to be first statement in file
word = "test"

def createBlank(word):
    for letter in word:
        print('_', end='')
createBlank(word)
```